functions of independent random variables with shared parameter dependences
Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables. The standard theorem found in books states that $f(X)$ and $g(Y)$ are also independent regardless of the specific form of $f$ and $g$. However, suppose we have something like $f(X)=\sin(X)+c$ and $g(Y)=(c+1)^3Y^{1/(c+1)}$. Here there is a shared dependence on some real arbitrary parameter $c$. The value of $c$ clearly affects the distributions of both $f(X)$ and $g(Y)$ so I cannot see how they are independent. The two functions could have many shared parameters in which case the same inconsistency is reached.

The point is that $c$ is fixed at the outset. It has nothing to do with the randomness involved in $X, Y$.

Stochastically independence doesn't work the way you are thinking. Surely $f(X)$ and $g(Y)$ are stochastically independent  in your example.
